# Best practice to change argument type in c++

Tags: c++

I want to write a C++ function that adjusts type of second argument based on the first one. so I have something like this:

```
enum FtnType { FTN_A, FTN_B, FTN_C };

void bar( FtnType foo, const int arg = 0)
{
    switch(foo)
    {
        case 0:
           {
                void ftnA(arg);
                break;
           }
        case 1:
           {
                void ftnB();
                break;
           }
        case 2:
           {
                void ftnC(arg);
                break;
           }
    }
}
```

Now for `case 0` I want arg to be an integer, for `case 1` I don't want to use any argument and for `case 3` I want arg type to be float. I know I can cast type within the a case but that seems like a bad programming practice. What should be the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: A cast. `static_cast`, if you can.

Comment: How does the person calling `bar()` know what type it is going to decide it wants?

Comment: i think you'll need a template or an overload if you want `arg` to be either an `int` or a `float` when you call `bar`

Comment: @Snps sorry but that was a typo. it was suppose to be foo

Comment: Seems to me like the caller should have enough information to call `ftnA()` `ftnB()` or `ftnC()` directly no?

Comment: @Galik so in my case FtnType defines Cuda device constants to set, {MAXPTS, GAUSSIAN1D, GAUSSIAN2D, DERIVATIVE,...}. Naturally MAXPTS will be an integer and GAUSSIAN1D will have argument sigma as a float

Comment: @bbaldino  It seems like a bit overkill to overload the function just for 1 case. I could try templating but wouldn't it be then better to just cast the value?

Comment: @Ijlal cast the value where?  if you call `bar` as you have it now with a float, you'll lose the data as it's loaded into an int.  (in your code, if you call `bar(FTN_C, 4.2)` you'll end up calling `ftnC` with a value of `4`.  to be called with either an int or a float, `bar` has to have overloads or a generic type from a template.

Comment: @bbaldino yes, I've understood that the best solution in my case is to overload the function. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix a fun combination of compile-time and run-time logic. While you might be able to achieve something through the use of templates, by specifying argument one as a compile-time known value, I am not entirely sure it is advisable.

You ask for a best practice, and honestly I feel that a best practice would be to take a step back and rethink your design. Why do you need your function to work so differently based on parameter 1?

If you were to change the value of parameter 2, such as would be the case with [variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) used in classic `printf` like functions, then you would have a source of error that would be difficult to detect at compile time, and even harder to detect run-time.

You might consider a more compile time friendly approach using variadic templates (though I still recommend rethinking your design):

```
template <typename F, typename... T>
void bar(F func, T... params) {
    func(params...);
}
```

The good thing about this approach, is that accidentally passing the wrong parameter type, or number of parameters, will cause a compile time error. This approach will require you to know the function to execute outside of `bar` though.

```
void test1(int a, double b, char c) {
    std::cout << "test1(" << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ")\n";
}

void test2() {
    std::cout << "test2()\n";
}

int main() {
    bar(test1, 1, 2.1, 'c');
    bar(test2);
    return 0;
}
```

This test code can be found running here: http://ideone.com/vU30qn and outputs:

```
test1(1, 2.1, c)
test2()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that depending on the first argument you want to take different type for the second argument. C++ is a strong typed language, which implies that you need to know the value of the first argument at compile time. This brings us in the template territory (me happy). Another issue is that the second argument needs to be passed by reference if you hope to modify it.

```
enum class FtnType { ftn_a, ftn_b, ftn_c };

template <FtnType type> struct Modify;

template <> struct Modify<FtnType::ftn_a>
{
    static auto modify(int& a)
    {
        ftnA(a);
    }
}

template <> struct Modify<FtnType::ftn_b>
{
    static auto modify()
    {
        ftnB();
    }
}

template <> struct Modify<FtnType::ftn_c>
{
    static auto modify(float& a)
    {
        ftnC(a);
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 24;
    float f = 42.f;

    Modify<FtnType::ftn_a>::modify(a);
    Modify<FtnType::ftn_b>::modify();
    Modify<FtnType::ftn_c>::modify(f);
}
```

This works by having a struct templated by `FtnType` and each specialization for `FtnType` has a different signature static `modify` function.

Answer (score 0):

not sure i'm understanding your problem right, but would an overload like this work?

```
void bar (int arg)
{
   ftnA(arg);
}

void bar (float arg)
{
   ftnC(arg);
}

void bar ()
{
   ftnB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need all these functions and `enum`. Just use overloaded functions:

```
void ftn(int arg)
{
   std::cout << "I've got an int!" << std::endl;
   // Do stuff which is in ftnA
}

void ftn(float arg)
{
   std::cout << "I've got an float!" << std::endl;
   // Do stuff which is in ftnC
}

void ftn()
{
   std::cout << "I've got nothing! :(" << std::endl;
   // Do stuff which is in ftnB
}
```

and simply call

```
ftn(5);    // Will print 'I've got an integer!'
ftn(5.0f); // Will print 'I've got an float!'
ftn();     // Will print 'I've got nothing! :('
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum class FtnType {FTN_A, FTN_B, FTN_C};

void bar(FtnType foo, const int arg = 0) {
    [&] {
        switch(foo) {
            case FtnType::FTN_A:
                return ftnA(arg);
            case FtnType::FTN_B:
                return ftnB();
            case FtnType::FTN_C:
                return ftnC(static_cast<double>(arg));
        }
    }();
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50b7d43f24b5c665)